# select built in audio analog stereo as microphone for firefox ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, microphone

I have problem to use my earphone microphone in Firefox
now by using alsamixer my built in analog stereo is my earphone mic.

When I want to get access a site to my microphone there is only 'monitor of built in Audio-analog Stereo' in the list and I cannot select built in analog stereo.

[image: pic1]

Also in pavucontrol recording tab I can not select Firefox microphone to built in audio analog stereo
[image: pic2]

(built in audio analog stereo is available in the list but I can not select it)

But I don't have this problem with other apps like Skype and Zoom

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not have a sound control setting so pavucontrol is taking the sound request directly from the app on the page in firefox maybe try checking the setting there.

Also what app/webpage and what ver ubuntu?